# Destiny expansions 1 and 2 and taken king

Tags: destiny

Will the expansions download right away?

I redeemed my codes but nothing happened. I have enough space and I'm playing on a first gen 360.

Will it download once I progress to that point in the story?

Comment: I believe those expansions are included in The Taken King download, so you should be okay. Not 100% sure as I purchased them both last year.

Comment: Well I used both codes and nothing happened. Is it suppose to download immediately or just once you have done everything in the original destiny?

Comment: I think it just enables them for you account, as the new Destiny client includes those expansions by default. I would hold on to your codes though, to be safe. Hopefully someone has a concrete answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have redeemed the codes and they are valid, and you have enough space, they should start downloading automatically.

If the downloads for the expansions don't start automatically, you can start them manually by going to the store page for each expansion and start the download from there (if the redeem was successful, you will not have to buy the expansions, it should just say "download").

You do not need a certain completion in-game to be able to download the expansions.

Comment: This is a bit misleading because the codes actual download a very small file and not the expansion itself. The base game contains all the necessary data and all you need is an appropriate licence. On my xb1 the two downloads for the expansions were about 10 meg each.

Comment: Indeed, the additional content supplemented to the game will download when starting the actual game. The files you download when you redeem your code is basically an activator, telling the game that you are enrolled to access this content. I was assuming this is what @Jeff was relating to when he said _"I redeemed my codes but nothing happened."_? Without these files downloaded first, the game will not let you access the content of the expansions.

Answer (score 0):

Some DLC that are activated with a code can download automatically. If it hasn't downloaded then, go into the online store on you xbox and search for the DLC.

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

They have probably downloaded, but you won't see any real changes in game until you're far enough along in the story.

Answer (score 0):

The data for the expansions is rolled up into the base game itself. When you purchase any of the addons you are basically just buying a licence and on the XB1 at least these files are about 10Mb each. I mention this because you may well have been expecting a large and lengthy download whereas in fact what downloaded probably happened almost instantly.

You should be able to access all features from the expansions immediately once you reach appropriate level to actually do so with no additional download needed.

You should also be able to view what DLC you have installed on your system. I'm sadly not 100% sure how on the 360 (been a while since I used mine) but I'll try to find some instructions somewhere.